# symfony Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I am just getting started with symfony and am trying to build the database but I get the following error:

```
./symfony doctrine:build --model
```

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is
>   not an array in
>   /home/nicky/symfony/symfony-1.4.8/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBaseTask.class.php
>   on line 182

I have the following in schema.yml

```
# config/doctrine/schema.yml
JobeetCategory:
actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
columns:
name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
JobeetJob:
actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
columns:
category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
type:         { type: string(255) }
company:      { type: string(255), notnull: true }
logo:         { type: string(255) }
url:          { type: string(255) }
position:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
location:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
description:  { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
how_to_apply: { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
token:        { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
is_public:    { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
is_activated: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
email:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
expires_at:   { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's how your file actually looks, it's not valid YAML. It's an indentation based language, and you have no indentation under your model names.

Comment: Unable to parse file "/home/nicky/symfony/projectdirectory/config/doctrine/schema.yml": A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 3 ( actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }).

Comment: That's correct, YAML uses spaces, not tabs. http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_sub_yaml_syntax_and_symfony_conventions